# Why is "modest" weaker than "moderate"

Tags: word-difference

> A quick reading of Fed language alongside contemporaneous‎ economic
>   data shows that **"modest" is a touch weaker than "moderate,"** with a
>   threshold a bit below 2% gross domestic product growth, though it
>   doesn’t seem to be an exact science.
>
> From
>   https://blogs.wsj.com/economics/2013/08/01/fedspeak-whats-the-difference-between-modest-and-moderate/

When I looked up these two words, they seem to be similar.

> Modest: limited in size, amount, or scope
>
> Moderate:limited in scope or effect (Merriam Webster)

Why is "modest" weaker than "moderate"? I cannot see the difference in their definitions.

Answer (score -1):

"Moderate" is language-cousings to moderators who are a neutral middle party in debates, and moderation, the limiting of excess, (in debates but also some other places)

So you give the idea of something that used to be excessive and is now brought back to a more neutral, middle ground.

Modesty has a meaning that is similar but approaches it from the other side: dressing modeslt never meant "fabulous glitter suit, but dulled down" and your modest colleague was never someone to boast.

So both end up in the middle but from two different directions and as humans we generally prefer the winners, the moderate ones, who could be amazing if only they were not moderated.

But the meanings are very close.

(sorry mods, nothing against you)